# Metrizability of an one-point compactification

Tags: general-topology

I am trying to prove the characterization of metrizability of locally compact metric space $(X,d)$:

> Let $X^*$ be the one-point compactification of $(X,d)$. Then $X^*$
> is metrizable if and only if there exists a proper continuous map
> $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ which is bounded from below.

I can prove the sufficient condition by defining the function $f$ by $f(x)=d(x,\infty)$ where $X^*=X\cup\{\infty\}$ and it is easy to check its continuity and properness.

But I am stuck proving the necessary condition. I was trying to define $d(x,\infty):=f(x)+M$ where $M$ is the lower bound for $f$. But I found that $f$ may not be injective and such definition for distance does not make sense.

Any help will be aprreciated.

Comment: $X^\ast$ is metrisable iff $X$ is separable, in this case. Maybe you can check separability from the existence of $f$?

Comment: $f(x)=d(x,\infty)$ is also not 1-1 in the sufficiency proof.

Comment: oh! I was thinking about $d(x,\infty)$ iff $x=\infty$. I guess injectivity may not 
a problem. But the triangle inequality inequality $f(x)\le f(y)+d(x,y)$ may be a problem. @HennoBrandsma

Answer (score 1):

You want to show that if there exists a proper continuous map $f : X \rightarrow \mathbb R$ which is bounded from below, then $X^*$ is metrizable.

In fact we do not need to assume that $f$ is bounded from below, it suffices to assume that $f$ is proper. Also note that that if you have any proper $\bar f :  X \rightarrow \mathbb R$, then $f = \lvert \bar f \rvert$ is proper and bounded from below.

All $X_n = f^{-1}([-n,n])$ are compact and $X_n \subset f^{-1}((-(n+1),n+1)) \subset X_{n+1}$, hence $X_n \subset \text{int} X_{n+1}$.

All $X_n$ are compact metric, thus second countable. Hence also all $\text{int} X_n$ are second countable and therefore also $X = \bigcup \text{int} X_n$ is second countable. Therefore also $X^*$ is second countable (note that the $X^* \setminus X_n$ form a neigborhood base of $\infty \in X^*$). Hence $X^*$ is metrizable.

Comment: I am wondering if $X_n=[-n,n]$ works, then the boundedness of $f$ may be removed?

Comment: Also, I am wondering why $X^*/X_n$ for a local base of $\infty$? is it possible that there exists a compact set in $X$ intersection all $X_n$?

Comment: @xyz 1. You are right, if $f$ is proper, then the boundedness from below is irrelevant in the above proof. As you say,  take $X_n = f^{-1}([-n,n])$. Anyway, if there exists a proper $f$, then $\lvert f \rvert$ is proper and bounded from below. 2. Each compact $K \subset X$ is covered by the $\text{int} X_n$, thus contained in the union of finitely many $\text{int} X_n$ and hence contained in some $X_N$.

Comment: @xyz I made an update of my answer.